# Where does Windows 7 store bluetooth phone contacts and calendar data?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, calendar, contacts, phone

Windows 7 has feature can help you connect mobile phone via bluetooth. I wonder where Windows 7 stores bluetooth phone contacts and calendar data as I could not find it in documents location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent done this personally, but its saved in a folder named after the bluetooth device it was connected to.

So you could do a search for that device name

[SOURCE](http://www.dkszone.net/backup-restore-contacts-calendar-info-bluetooth-phone-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

in my case : (Lenovo thinkpad W7 pro)

the backup data are stored in :

```
C:\Users\*usuername*\AppData\Local\Broadcom\Bluetooth Software\BluetoothDeviceBackups
```